# Ansible: get current target host's IP address

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-template

How do you get the current host's IP address in a role?

I know you can get the list of groups the host is a member of and the hostname of the host but I am unable to find a solution to getting the IP address.

You can get the hostname by using `{{inventory_hostname}}` and the group by using `{{group_names}}`

I have tried things like `{{ hostvars[{{ inventory_hostname }}]['ansible_ssh_host'] }}`
and `ip="{{ hostvars.{{ inventory_hostname }}.ansible_ssh_host }}"`

Answer (score 178, accepted):

A list of all addresses is stored in a fact `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses`, a default address in `ansible_default_ipv4.address`.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - debug: var=ansible_default_ipv4.address
```

Then there are addresses assigned to each network interface... In such cases you can display all the facts and find the one that has the value you want to use.

Comment: How do you display all flags?

Comment: `ansible <host> -m setup`, or `all` instead of hostname for all hosts in the inventory file

Comment: Can you list all flags from within a task?

Comment: @SJC Flags? You mean facts, right? Yes, run `setup:` module with `register: allfacts` and display with `- debug: var=allfacts`

Comment: the value of `gather_facts` must be`true` for this to work. it is true by default but one may turn it to false if the info about the hosts is not required.

Comment: Incorrect answer. Default IP address isn't necessarily the address ansible is using during the play

Comment: @poige It might be incorrect if you ask a new question, as you do.

Comment: this is not the address ansible connects to. It might match, but it does not have to.

Comment: Yes, `ansible_default_ipv4` is not always the required IPv4 of a specific NIC. It's just the address of the NIC that is in the `default` route (e.g. check output of `ip route` or read more here https://medium.com/opsops/ansible-default-ipv4-is-not-what-you-think-edb8ab154b10 )

Answer (score 99):

You can get the IP address from `hostvars`, dict `ansible_default_ipv4` and key `address`

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
```

and IPv6 address respectively

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv6']['address']
```

An example playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
    - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv6']['address']
```

Comment: This might fail in some cases, see this: https://medium.com/opsops/ansible-default-ipv4-is-not-what-you-think-edb8ab154b10

Comment: this is not the address ansible connects to. It might match, but it does not have to

Answer (score 34):

Just use `ansible_ssh_host` variable

> playbook_example.yml

```
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
  - name: Show host's ip
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
```

> hosts.yml

```
[hosts]
host1   ansible_host=1.2.3.4
```

> Result

```
TASK [Show host's ip] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
     "msg": "1.2.3.4"
}
```

Comment: Ansible 2.0 has deprecated the “ssh” from `ansible_ssh_host`. And if `ansible_host` contains hostname instead of IP, `ansible_ssh_host` will also do.

Comment: I'm currently using version 2.10 of ansible and this code works as charm in my case.

Answer (score 29):

You can use in your template.j2 `{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}` the same way you use `{{inventory_hostname}}`.

ps: Please refer to the following blogpost to have more information about [HOW TO COLLECT INFORMATION ABOUT REMOTE HOSTS WITH ANSIBLE GATHERS FACTS](https://www.data-essential.com/ansible-how-to-collect-information-about-remote-hosts-with-gathers-facts/)
.

'hoping it’ll help someone one day ッ

Comment: Be extra careful. Nowadays the default network interface is not always 'eth0'. It sometimes called `ens3` or `enp2s0` and such things. You have just better bets if you use `ansible_default_ipv4` and if it's not working, then switch back looking for some sane defaults.

Comment: This probably used to work in the past but with Ansible 2.7 this variable is undefined.

Comment: this is not the address ansible connects to. It might match, but it does not have to

Answer (score 14):

Simple debug command:

```
ansible -i inventory/hosts.yaml -m debug -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]" all
```

output:

```
"hostvars[inventory_hostname]": {
    "ansible_check_mode": false, 
    "ansible_diff_mode": false, 
    "ansible_facts": {}, 
    "ansible_forks": 5, 
    "ansible_host": "192.168.10.125", 
    "ansible_inventory_sources": [
        "/root/workspace/ansible-minicros/inventory/hosts.yaml"
    ], 
    "ansible_playbook_python": "/usr/bin/python2", 
    "ansible_port": 65532, 
    "ansible_verbosity": 0, 
    "ansible_version": {
        "full": "2.8.5", 
        "major": 2, 
        "minor": 8, 
        "revision": 5, 
        "string": "2.8.5"
    },
```

get host ip address:

```
ansible -i inventory/hosts.yaml -m debug -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_host" all

zk01 | SUCCESS => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_host": "192.168.10.125"
}
```

Comment: `ansible_host` might contain hostname

Comment: Like @LogicDaemon said, `ansible_host` is whatever you defined in your inventory, so this does not always print the IP address.

Answer (score 12):

Plain `ansible_default_ipv4.address` might not be what you think in [some cases](https://medium.com/opsops/ansible-default-ipv4-is-not-what-you-think-edb8ab154b10), use:

```
ansible_default_ipv4.address|default(ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0])
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer here, per the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts)

Answer (score 7):

Another way to find public IP would be to use `uri` module:

```
    - name: Find my public ip
      uri: 
        url: http://ifconfig.me/ip
        return_content: yes
      register: ip_response
```

Your IP will be in `ip_response.content`

Comment: Another service url that returns the same is: `https://ipecho.net/plain`

Comment: @PaulParker https://ipecho.net/plain seems KO or ask api token ... ifconfig.me better and stable service since years :+1

Comment: Never been asked for an API token. I cannot speak to the consistency of the service, I haven't monitored it, but it has never failed me.

Answer (score 6):

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dig.html

so in template, for e. g.:

```
{{ lookup('dig', ansible_host) }}
```

Notes:

- Since not only DNS name could be used in inventory a check if it's not IP already better be added
- Obviously enough this receipt wouldn't work as intended for indirect host specifications (like using jump hosts, for e. g.)

But still it serves 99 % (figuratively speaking) of use cases.

Comment: And what if DNS is not used in the environment?

Comment: (Or, I feel your pain. Otherwise you won't ask naive questions like that.) — If DNS isn't used in inventory one just use ansible_host directly as indicated in my answer.

Comment: Abs what if `ansible_host` is not the IP address of the host in question?

Comment: this is not "and what". It's just "what" cause your previously asked question isn't counted, don't forget.

Comment: "get current target host's IP address" — current target host is specified by inventory; it can be either given by DNS name or by IP-address. Both are explained. Don't suffer much

Comment: I have no clue what you are saying; certainly you haven’t answered my clarifying question. So you assume all hosts are accessed either through a DNS address or their real IP address, right?

Comment: I have no clue what you are calling as "real IP address". Do you know some unreal ones?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169475/discussion-between-poige-and-techraf).

Comment: Real IP address is the one set on the target itself. Unlike the one you might be accessing server with.

Comment: Why didn't you use term real DNS address then? O_o "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" — I've answered there hours ago

Comment: Because I did not find it appropriate to formulate my thought using words you suggested. Sorry, I am using StackOverflow app, it neither suggests anything nor supports chat. Does it bother you?

Comment: Your inconsistency your mean?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the **external public IP** and you're in a cloud environment like AWS or Azure, you can use the [ipify_facts module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ipify_facts_module.html):

```
# TODO: SECURITY: This requires that we trust ipify to provide the correct public IP. We could run our own ipify server.
- name: Get my public IP from ipify.org
  ipify_facts:
```

This will place the public IP into the variable `ipify_public_ip`.

Comment: This does not always work. For me `ipify_public_ip` variable is empty

Comment: For AWS, inventory_hostname will be the ip address.

Comment: This plugin can work within a certain set of circumstances, if you're accessing the internet from behind a NAT, it won't work. Basically this works when the servers are accessible to the internet and can hit the ipify.org website to resolve their external IP when accessing the site.

Comment: @BerenddeBoer Wrong. `inventory_hostname` is whatever is set in the inventory. It could be a host name as set in `.ssh/config`.

Comment: @slm as I said, if you're looking for the external public IP. If you're behind a NAT, then you won't have an external publicly accessible IP so you wouldn't use this method.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will return the public ip of the remote machine and also default ip(i.e: LAN)

This will print ip's in quotes also to avoid confusion in using config files.

```html
>> main.yml

---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: ipify
      ipify_facts:
    - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ipify_public_ip']
    - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
    - name: template
      template:
        src: debug.j2
        dest: /tmp/debug.ansible

>> templates/debug.j2

public_ip={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ipify_public_ip'] }}
public_ip_in_quotes="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ipify_public_ip'] }}"

default_ipv4={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}
default_ipv4_in_quotes="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
```

Comment: Some comments by you would improve this answer

Comment: `ipify:` is a community module.  You'll soon need to use `community.genereal.ipify:` to access it.  Answers consisting of only code are discouraged on SO.  Explain how this works.

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me:

```
this_node_ip: '{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_env'].SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2] }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had needed to keep the IP and then run a command using `delegate_to`, so I wrote something as follows in variables:

```bash
leader_ip: '{{ansible_ssh_host}}'
```

and then I used the `leader_ip`.

the other solution is to use `hostvar`:

```bash
hostvars[INVENTORY_HOSTNAME]['ansible_host']
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get **ansible_default_ipv4**. Actually it would be empty when *default route* cannot be set.

I use

```yaml
   - name: IPv4
     ansible.builtin.debug:
       msg:
         ipv4: "{{ ansible_facts['env'].SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below expression.

eg in a task:

- name: IPv4
  ansible.builtin.debug:
  msg:
  ipv4: "{{ ansible_facts['default_ipv4']['address'] }}"

In a jinja template just put the below expression where your ip needs to be present

{{ ansible_facts['default_ipv4']['address'] }}