# Docker_swarm module - join_token parameter for ansible not working

Tags: docker, module, ansible, swarm

This is my ansible playbook, the tasks are copied from docker_swarm module documentation so it should work:

```
  - name: Init a new swarm with default parameters
    docker_swarm:
      state: present
      advertise_addr: "{{ manager_ip }}:2377"
    register: rezult
    when: "ansible_default_ipv4.address == '{{ manager_ip }}'"


  - name: Add nodes
    docker_swarm:
      state: join
      advertise_addr: "{{ manager_ip }}"
      join_token: rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker
      remote_addrs: "{{ manager_ip }}:2377"
    when: "ansible_default_ipv4.address != '{{ manager_ip }}'"
```

It inits a swarm manager with the "manager_ip" --extra-var
but it fails in the "add nodes task" with this error:

```
fatal: [vm2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Can not join the Swarm Cluster: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error (\"invalid join token\")"}
```

if I put "'{{ }}'" around "rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker" after join_token I get this:

```
fatal: [vm2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'swarm_facts'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ansible/docker-ansible/docker.yml': line 47, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Add nodes\n    ^ here\n"}
```

If I put the debug msg for rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker I get the correct token:

```
ok: [opensuse1] => {
    "msg": "SWMTKN-1-5p7brhxxz4gzu716t78tt5woj7h6aflq0kdwvzwlbbe7ct0ba7-e59bg0t79q67ogd61ydwxc5yq"
}
```

and If I use that token manually with the docker swarm join command on the server I wish to merge with manager it works. So the variable has the correct value and the connection between nodes work. But I just can't get join_token to work. I am running ansible 2.8.5 with python 2.7.5.

I know I can use the shell module but I do not want to do that.

Comment: Also, I get the same second error when using the shell module. I think ansible just forgets what is in "rezult" when running on a server that it "!= '{{ manager_ip }}'". This is frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this works for me:

```
---
- name: Init swarm on the first node
  community.general.docker_swarm:
    state: present
    advertise_addr: "{{ ansible_host }}"
  register: result
  when: inventory_hostname == groups['swarm_managers'][0]

- name: Get join-token for manager nodes
  set_fact:
    join_token_manager: "{{ hostvars[groups['swarm_managers'][0]].result.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Manager }}"

- name: Get join-token for worker nodes
  set_fact:
    join_token_worker: "{{ hostvars[groups['swarm_managers'][0]].result.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker }}"

- name: Join other managers
  community.general.docker_swarm:
    state: join
    join_token: "{{ join_token_manager }}"
    advertise_addr: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    remote_addrs: "{{ hostvars[groups['swarm_managers'][0]].ansible_host }}"
  when:
    - inventory_hostname in groups['swarm_managers']
    - inventory_hostname != groups['swarm_managers'][0]

- name: Join workers
  community.general.docker_swarm:
    state: join
    join_token: "{{ join_token_worker }}"
    advertise_addr: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    remote_addrs: "{{ hostvars[groups['swarm_managers'][0]].ansible_host }}"
  when:
    - inventory_hostname not in groups['swarm_managers']
```

In `swarm_managers` group there are managers and all other hosts from this inventory are workers.

Comment: Love this, but are you not missing `when: inventory_hostname == groups['swarm_managers'][0]` from the "Get join-token" tasks?

Comment: @LennartRolland After the init task, the only host that knows the join tokens is `groups['swarm_managers'][0]`. And we want to make these tokens available for all hosts in inventory. So, in the next 2 tasks, each host is setting `join_token_xxx` fact by getting these variables from `groups['swarm_managers'][0]` - the `hostvars[groups['swarm_managers'][0]]` part. 

The only `when` that can be added here, that I can think of, is `when: inventory_hostname in groups['swarm_managers']` for `Get join-token for manager nodes` task and vice versa for `Get join-token for worker nodes` task

Answer (score 2):

I think achempion was correct, the issue was that OPs variable `rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker` was not being evaluated, but rather provided as an object of sorts.

Replace `rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker` with `"{{ rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker }}"` and it should work.

I realise OP has probably already moved on but I have spent ages trying to figure out a very similar problem and this appeared to resolve it for me.

Answer (score 2):

As I have not enough reputation to comment - here is an other mistake in your playbooks task. You use:

```
  - name: Add nodes
    docker_swarm:
      state: join
      advertise_addr: "{{ manager_ip }}"
      join_token: rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker
      remote_addrs: "{{ manager_ip }}:2377"
    when: "ansible_default_ipv4.address != '{{ manager_ip }}'"
```

...which assigns the `advertise_addr` to the **wrong** ip address. This will still allow your nodes to join, but mess up their overlay network configuration (no node can ping each other, resulting in constant network failures). I would suggest to use the [ssh connection ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819378/ansible-get-current-target-hosts-ip-address) instead:

```
  - name: Add nodes
    docker_swarm:
      state: join
      advertise_addr: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
      join_token: rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker
      remote_addrs: "{{ manager_ip }}:2377"
    when: "ansible_default_ipv4.address != '{{ manager_ip }}'"
```

Also just take a look into the [documentation examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_swarm_module.html#examples):

```
- name: Add nodes
  community.docker.docker_swarm:
    state: join
    advertise_addr: 192.168.1.2
    join_token: SWMTKN-1--xxxxx
    remote_addrs: [ '192.168.1.1:2377' ]
```

...which also uses **different** ip addresses.

*I have to admit:* I also fall for it and it took several hours to solve. I hope someone else sees this answer before making the same mistake by just copying your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is from `rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker`. In debug info it appears as `"msg": "SWMTKN-1-5p7..."` but `join_token:` option from Ansible configuration expects it to be just plain token without additional wrappers as `"msg":` and so on.

Comment: I don't think it's "msg" that's the problem here, that's there in any debug message. Did you manage to figure this out? I have the same problem.