# Ansible getting public ip of host from inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to get public ip of a host defined in inventory file

```
[test-sites:children]
test-site-1

[test-site-1]
test-site-1-2 ipv4=192.168.0.1 ipv6=....
```

How do I get the ipv4 and ipv6 address of "test-site-1-2" defined in the inventory file? I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819378/ansible-get-current-target-hosts-ip-address) answer but it gives all of the addresses (public & private). I am interested in ips defined in the inventory file only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[test-site-1]
test-site-1-2 ipv4=192.168.0.1 ipv6=....
```

> Q: *"How do I get the ipv4 and ipv6 address of "test-site-1-2" defined in the inventory file?"*

A: If the playbook is running at "test-site-1-2" simply reference the variables directly. For example

```
- hosts: test-site-1-2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ipv4
    - debug:
        var: ipv6
```

If these variables are needed by other hosts reference to "hostvars" is needed. For example

```
- hosts: test-site-1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars['test-site-1-2'].ipv4
    - debug:
        var: hostvars['test-site-1-2'].ipv6
```

See [Basic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/first_inventory.html#basic-inventory).