# Ansible: Checking the IP address and depending on which address perform actions

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a playbook to everyone and I want to implement verification by IP address and depending on which subnet perform actions.

```yaml
---
- name: Install package
  hosts: "{{ myhosts }}"
  remote_user: user
  become_method: sudo
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: check
    #debug: var=ansible_default_ipv4.address
    shell: /usr/sbin/ip -4 a | egrep '10.50.0.|10.77.12.'
    register: check_ip

  - name: Example 1
    debug:
      msg: bla bla
    when: check_ip.stdout = 0

  - name: Example 2
    debug:
      msg: bla bla
    when: check_ip.stdout != 0
```

Is there is a more elegant solution? And how can mistakes be missed in these conditions? After all, one of the conditions will definitely be false.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there is a more elegant solution?*

At a first step you may start to get familiar with [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) with a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "default_ipv4"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"

  - name: Show interface and address
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.default_ipv4.interface }} has {{ ansible_facts.default_ipv4.address }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show interface and address] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: eth0 has 192.0.2.0
```

**Further Reading**

- [Is it possible to gather only specific facts in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692925/6771046)
- [What is the exact list of Ansible `setup` `min`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046)

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: Get current target host's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819378/)

---

> *I want to implement verification by IP address.*

As a second steps you may start to get familiar with [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) and with a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "default_ipv4"

  tasks:

  - name: Is IP in correct network block?
    debug:
      msg: "[OK] YES, IP is in RFC5737 TEST-NET-1 block (use in documentation)."
    when: ansible_facts.default_ipv4.address.startswith('192.0.2')
```

**Further Reading**

- [Using filters to manipulate data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html)
- [Testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)
- [Ansible conditionals - Wildcard match string](https://serverfault.com/questions/960575/)

---

Apart from the above examples

> *After all, one of the conditions will definitely be false.*

right, this is because of the [Common Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) and specifically the [`shell` Return Code](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#return-rc).

Have a look at

```sh
/usr/sbin/ip -4 a | egrep '10.50.0.|10.77.12.'; echo $?
```

and your example

```yaml
- name: Check IP block
    shell: /usr/sbin/ip -4 a | egrep '10.50.0.|10.77.12.'
    register: check_ip
    # Since it is a reporting task set
    failed_when: check_ip.rc != 0 and check_ip.rc != 1 # .rc > 1
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: false
```

because that's what is returned by `egrep` depending on

```yaml
  - name: IP block found
    debug:
      msg: FOUND
    when: check_ip.rc = 0

  - name: IP block not found
    debug:
      msg: NOT FOUND
    when: check_ip.rc = 1
```

If you like to utilize `stdout`, or in general, it might be better to change the command to count the result lines instead of depending on the Return Code (RC) in order to check if something was found or not

```yaml
    shell: /usr/sbin/ip -4 a | egrep '10.50.0.|10.77.12.' | wc -l
```

because that will leave you with result of `stdout` of `0` or greater than that and you could use

```yaml
when: check_ip.stdout | int = 0 # found nothing

# or

when: check_ip.stdout | int > 0 # found something
```