# Fail playbook if hostname from variable does not resolve to an IP from ansible_facts

Tags: list, dictionary, validation, ansible, dns

I am writing a playbook to set up a web application. Before I make any changes to the system I would like to validate that a hostname provided by passing a variable for the machine actually resolves to one of the IP addresses from ansible facts. If this isn't given the certificate generation later on will fail.

I am planning to get the results from [community.general.dig](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dig_lookup.html) and compare the A and AAAA keys in the result dictionary with IP addresses from the ansible facts all_ipv4_addresses/all_ipv6_addresses variables.

When one or a list of IP is in both dictionaries I want to continue with the playbook, else fail with a warning. These IPs I would like to reuse later to aquire the certificate.

I have looked into [complex data manipulation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) but I cannot make proper sense of how to chain the filters to get my desired result. I also am struggling with the fact i have to compare multiple lists or dictionaries with each other.

My original approach was to use the fail builtin and loop over both lists from DNSpython and ansible facts to check for a match. This is insufficient as I need to reuse the list of matching IPs later. The comparison with the `ansible_facts.default_ipv4.address` does not seem sufficient since they might have multiple network interfaces (ipv4 and 6) that might not be the default route.

The thought process I had in mind to validate if a certificate could be obtained should be to get all available IPs from `all_ipv4_addresses`/ `all_ipv6_addresses` and then store the intersection of these records with the valid A/AAAA records from resolving the `app_host` variable.

I have found the [intersect()](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/intersect_filter.html) filter and now I am just trying to put the entire thing in a condition. Thanks @U880D for pointing me in the right direction towards `ansible_facts`, whose snipped i have reused for the start of my playbook:

```yaml
- name: set up all app services on the target machine
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "network" # in order to get the actual Remote Node configuration

  become: yes
  vars:
    # always overwrite this with the previously setup FQDN
    - app_host:
    - app_vhost_webroot: /var/www/{{ app_host }}/public
    # no trailing / leading slash ; can be an subdirectory like 'app/wws' relative to webroot
    - app_path: wws
    - app_db: app
    - app_dbhost: localhost
    - app_dbuser: app
    - app_dbpassword: lookup('community.general.random_string', length=14, min_lower=1, min_upper=1, min_numeric=1, special=false)
#    - app_customization_branch: ith
    # eventually fill this automatically from calling git using branch name above
    # no trailing / leading slash ; relative to app_path ; multiple customizations not yet supported
    - app_customization_branch_dir: anpassungen/ith
    - max_upload_size: '30M'
    - phpversion: '7.2'
    - dhparams_file: /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem

  tasks:
    - name: Check if app_host is set
      ansible.builtin.fail:
        msg: This playbook requires a FQDN set as app_host
      when: app_host is undefined or app_host == '' or app_host == None

    - name: Check if app_host resolves to an IPv4 address shared of the target machine
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('community.general.dig', app_host, qtype='A', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv4_addresses) }}"

    - name: Check if app_host resolves to an IPv6 address shared of the target machine
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('community.general.dig', app_host, qtype='AAAA', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv6_addresses) }}"
```

All that is left would be to a 3rd task that would fail the playbook when theyre both empty. Currently I am strugging to move the variable from `msg:` to `when:` cause ansible complains about the use of J2 templating delimiters:

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ lookup('community.general.dig', app_host, qtype='A', wantlist=True) |
intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv4_addresses) }}
```

All I would like to do would be to add both lists of intersections together and ansible.builtin.fail when they union of both intersections I just created is empty. I thought of a when condition like:

`{{ {{ lookup('community.general.dig', app_host, qtype='A', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv4_addresses) }} | union({{ lookup('community.general.dig', app_host, qtype='AAAA', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv6_addresses) }}) }} == []`

but I seem to be not understanding something vital in how to build these expressions.

Comment: This a yaml error so your playbook did not even start to run. Your variable is not declared correctly anyway. Even though the error might be elsewhere in your file as reported by the error message, try with the following: `ipv4s_cert: "{{ lookup('community.general.dig', app_host, qtype='A', wantlist=True) }}"` (same fix for the next line)

Comment: This still fails with the same error sadly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

worked it out: using `union()` and `intersect()` filters:

```yaml
{{ lookup('community.general.dig', APP_HOST, qtype='A', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv4_addresses) }}
```

This would produce a list of matching ipv4 addresses. Replace `ipv4` with `ipv6` and set `qtype='AAAA'` for ipv6. Then union() both lists.

```yaml
- name: set up all app services on the target machine
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "network" # in order to get the actual Remote Node configuration
  become: yes
  vars:
    - APP_HOST:


  tasks:
    - name: Fail when APP_HOST is unset
      ansible.builtin.fail:
        msg: This playbook requires a FQDN set as APP_HOST
      when: APP_HOST is undefined or APP_HOST == '' or APP_HOST == None

    - name: Check if IP addresses from node match resolvable IPs for given FQDN
      assert:
        that:
          - lookup('community.general.dig', APP_HOST, qtype='A', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv4_addresses) != [] or lookup('community.general.dig', APP_HOST, qtype='AAAA', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv6_addresses) != []
        success_msg: "{{ lookup('community.general.dig', APP_HOST, qtype='A', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv4_addresses) | union(lookup('community.general.dig', APP_HOST, qtype='AAAA', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv6_addresses)) }}"
        fail_msg: "No matching hostname/IP combinations found for {{ APP_HOST }} and {{ ansible_facts.all_ipv4_addresses | union( ansible_facts.all_ipv6_addresses ) }}"
      register: certificate_eligible

    - name: all done
      ansible.builtin.fail:
        msg: "{{ certificate_eligible.msg }}"
```

I couldnt figure out how to populate a variable other than `msg` through assert but this is good enough. Output when there is a match:

```bash
ansible-playbook -l 'deb11test' -b app_defaults.yaml -e APP_HOST=valid.local.domain
PLAY [set up all app services on the target machine] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host deb11test is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python3.9, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.14/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
ok: [deb11test]

TASK [Fail when APP_HOST is unset] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [deb11test]

TASK [Check if IP addresses from node match resolvable IPs for given FQDN] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [deb11test] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": [
        "192.168.1.134"
    ]
}

TASK [all done] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [deb11test]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": ["192.168.1.134"]}
```

else when no valid domain is used:

```
PLAY [set up all app services on the target machine] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host deb11test is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python3.9, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.14/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
ok: [deb11test]

TASK [Fail when APP_HOST is unset] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [deb11test]

TASK [Check if IP addresses from node match resolvable IPs for given FQDN] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [deb11test]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "lookup('community.general.dig', APP_HOST, qtype='A', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv4_addresses) != [] or lookup('community.general.dig', APP_HOST, qtype='AAAA', wantlist=True) | intersect(ansible_facts.all_ipv6_addresses) != []",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "No matching hostname/IP combinations found for invalid-domain and ['192.168.1.134', 'fd00::a00:27ff:fe17:2172', 'fe80::a00:27ff:fe17:2172']"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *How to check if a hostname from variable resolves to the same IP as the `ansible_host` before continuing?*

From your given example I'am missing the part where the inventory hostname becomes compared with the DNS entries after lookup. Do you mean an approach like

```yaml
---
- hosts: test # ansible_play_hosts gathered from inventory
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "network" # in order to get the actual Remote Node configuration

  vars:

    APP_HOST: test1.example.com

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.default_ipv4.address }}"

  - name: Check if APP_HOST resolves to the same IP as the Remote Node
    assert:
      that:
        - ansible_facts.default_ipv4.address == lookup('community.general.dig', APP_HOST, qtype='A')
      fail_msg: "NO"
      success_msg: "YES"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Check if APP_HOST resolves to the same IP as the Remote Node] ***********************************
ok: [test1.example.com] => changed=false
  msg: 'YES'
fatal: [test2.example.com]: FAILED! => changed=false
  assertion: ansible_facts.default_ipv4.address == lookup('community.general.dig', APP_HOST, qtype='A')
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: 'NO'

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************
test1.example.com : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
test2.example.com : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**Other Q&A**

regarding

- [Ansible: Checking the IP address and depending on which address perform actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76179381/6771046)

Comment: The hostname should come from ansible_host variable in inventory, i accidentally wrote "ssh_host" instead of "ansible_host" cause i was thinking about "ansible_ssh_host" ;       when: {{ item.ipaddr }} not in ipv4s_cert or {{ item.ipaddr }} not in ipv6s_cert causing a failure would be the part to terminate the playbook

Comment: @siryx, than, you may update your initial question with a more detailed description.

Comment: im working on it, it was closed for having typos and im trying to figure out how to make it better

Comment: @siryx - actually it was closed because the reviewers felt that your issue was a typo.  That is, the issue was resolved and no one else is likely to learn from it.  Voting to reopen it now.